# typescript append const if variable is true

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In typescript, is there a better way to clean up followed code? if we have id parameter, then I want to return id with const postfix. if we do not have id parameter, then just return postifx

```
function func(id?: number) {

  const postfix = 'append'
    if (id) {
      return `${id}${postfix}`
     }
    else {
      return postfix
    }
}
console.log(func())
console.log(func(0))
console.log(func(1))
console.log(func(12))
```

Comment: How is this TypeScript (or even the relatively old TypeScript 2.x) specific? Plain ES6: `return \`${id || ''}append\``.

Answer (score 2):

you can simplify this code with defalut value for id (in ES5 style):

```
function func(id?: number) {
  return `${id || ''}append`
}
```

or if it's important to have `postfix` const:

```
function func(id?: number) {
 const postfix = 'append';
 return `${id || ''}${postfix}`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test it right now, but like in many other programming languages you can use ternary operator.

For example:

```
function func(id?: number) {

  const postfix = 'append'
  return id != null ? `${id}${postfix}` : postfix

}
```